# Is it possible to create a custom event log in event viewer?

Tags: windows, events

I want a custom event log in windows event viewer that will capture only one kind of event so I don't have to filter out the security log in my application?  Context is I am writing an app that will capture one type of event and log it to a file and email it to the boss.  I have successfully created it but I really don't like having to sift through multiple types of events if I really am only looking for one type so I figured on the OS level I could create a log that only captures that one type and then set my app to read from that log.

Comment: I don't follow. You want to create an event log that's exclusively for a single event type, to save your program from filtering input? What's the rationale for that?

Comment: It may be my inexperience w Windows auditing but there is way too much noise in the log from other os events.   I want to just log file reads.  Really events between I'd 4000-5000 are what I want.